# how to calculate sum of qty column from two tables in sql

Tags: mysql

i m new commer in SQL Language pls help me to calculate sum from two tables one is purchase and second is sale
but result in stock is wrong
purchase(tb)

```
  itemcode  itemname    qty
    1       1100        10
    2       1110        15
    3       1600        10
```

sale(tb)

```
itemcode    itemname    qty
1       1100        5
2       1110        10
```

stock(query) as result

```
itemcode    itemname    qty
1       1100        ?
2       1110        ?
3       1600        ?
```

pls arrange a suitable script for its stock result
 thanks

Comment: Show the query which has wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

insert into stock(itemcode,itemname,qty)
select itemcode,itemname,sum(qty)
from
(
    select itemcode,itemname,qty
    from purchase
    union all
    select itemcode,itemname,qty
    from sale
) s
group by itemcode